# Wrap and inner-wrap HTML with Emmet

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, emmet

Using WebStorm or PhpStorm, is there any way to achieve the following productivity boost via Emmet or any other magic?

1. Having some multiline text pasted from a text editor or email:

   ```
   Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3
   Item 4
   ```

   have each line wrapped in, say, `<li>`?

   ```
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   ```
2. Having some `<li>` items,

   ```
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   ```

   inner-wrap the text with, say, `<a href="#"> ... </a>`?

   ```
   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
   ```

I find myself in need of such a productivity boost, Emmet being my first suspect, but my attempts failed.

Comment: So .. what have you tried? Because #1 (and #2 directly from #1 leaving intermediate step aside) is definitely possible with Emmet.

Comment: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Comment: Tried many syntax, but without the necessary placeholder, thanks.

Comment: So .. the issue is resolved, as I understand?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing me to the demo. The answer for #1 is `li*`

Answer (score 4):

In PhpStorm 8 you can do this in such a way:

Code -> Surround with (you can use CTRL + SHIFT + T) -> Emmet. You'll get field where you can write `ul>li*` to get this task completed.

For achieving more productivity you need fast access to this tool. You can get it in a such way:
Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap, find surround with Emmet (there is a search line) and add preferred keybord shortcut for this action.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

suppose you wanna have a `<nav>`, inside that wanna have `<ul>`, inside that wanna have an `<li>` tags for each item, inside every `<li>` you wanna have `<a>` tag (with href="#"). Every `<a>` tag wraps an item directly.

In Brackets + Emmet I do as follows,

Select the list of items, say

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

press ctrl+shift+a (this shortcut works in brackets, other editors may have another shortcut) to enter emmet's abbreviation mode, and type `nav>ul>li>a[href="#"]*` . The resulting code with be as follows

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">one</a>
            <a href="#">two</a>
            <a href="#">three</a>
            <a href="#">four</a>
            <a href="#">five</a>
            <a href="#">six</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Remember, `*` is important at the end of the abbreviation, otherwise emmet will think you wanna wrap all the items in a single `<a>` tag

Edit:
If you put '*' after li not at the end (like this `nav>ul>li*>a[href="#"]`) you'll get more beautiful result as required in most cases, means every `<a>` will be wrapped in its own `<li>`.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

in php storm use:

> CTRL + ALT + T

select `emmet` from menu and write code...

Answer (score 0):

I *only* know how to do this is Sublime + Emmet, but:

For #1, select you raw multiline text.

1. Hit `Ctrl + Shift + L` (Cmd on Mac) to separate each line as a selection
2. `Ctrl + Alt + Enter` to enter abbreviation mode.
3. Input `li` as the abbreveation, wrapping each line of content in a `<li>` tag.

   For #2
4. Input `li>a[href=#]` as the abbreviation. I would recommend a simple `li>a` since the cursor will be there to input the correct url reference unless you can input a simple rule.

**For note:** Be sure to check your key-bindings, since you are explicitly using a different IDE than me, you'll need to know how to use Multiple cursor/line selections in PHPStorm etc (if it is possible).

Additionally, in this particular example it is important to note that the wrapped content will appear **LAST**.

This means something like `li*3` would give you 12 items, with only 4 as content. The content will appear in the last item (every 4th item in this example) so just be careful with multiline line, multi cursor workflow.